# "Тим-лидер" - варваризм или необходимое заимствование?

Tags: заимствования

В современной публицистике и рекламной литературе получило широкое распространение выражение "тим-лидер" (варианты написания: "тим лидер", "Тим Лидер"). Насколько оправдано его употребление в русском контексте? Есть ли необходимость в заимствовании данного оборота?

Answer (score 2):

К инициаторам такого заимствования неизбежны вопросы.

1. Этому уже предшествовало заимствование слова "тим" (команда или группа), которое предлагается прикрутить к имеющемуся "лидеру"? Или это в дальнейших планах? Раньше люди работали "в коллективе", позже "в команде" - теперь "в тиме" будут?
2. Чем это по смыслу отличается от обычных "лидера группы", просто "лидера" названной общности людей или "руководителя" (в более формальном случае)?

Что касается варварства: не от перетаскивания ли этой "тим" в своё время возникло просторечное "команда" по отношению к какой-нибудь рок-группе? Музыканты, творческие люди, уподобляются при этом пожарному расчёту с командиром во главе. Из области варварства по отношению к русской грамматике и попытки раздельного написания предлагаемого термина - зависимое существительное, неспособное склоняться, ставится перед основным: "команда лидер Петров" - пусть читатель угадывает, как связаны слова. Вот если бы оно склонялось - другое дело (козы барабанщик и т. п.). Можно, конечно, через дефис написать ("тим-лидер"), но зачем нужно само слово - командой "чирлидерш" рукововодить?

Трудно сказать, что хуже в попытках читающих на незнакомом языке людей: перенести оттуда слово по буквам или взять какое-нибудь из его значений в словаре.

Answer (score 2):

Вполне нормальное заимствование, которое, как и любое другое слово, уместно в подходящем контексте. Мне кажется, что именно в рекламе и публицистике «тим-лидер» — это не то, чем повсеместно должно быть заменено «лидер команды»: в таком случае налицо стилистическая ошибка. Тем не менее, если в публицистическом тексте рассказывается, например, о компьютерных играх, то «тим-лидер» более правдоподобное название лидера группы в игре, нежели общелитературный аналог.

Почему именно «тим-лидер»? Очевидно, из-за краткости, лаконичности. (Собственно, «командир» заменилось «лидером» по схожей причине.)

P. S. В одной игре лидер группы (рейда) вообще обозначается аббревиатурой РЛ (от англ. *raid leader*). Из-за того же.